# Can I download & use Visual Basic in Ubuntu?

Tags: microsoft

I have a school project for programming with Visual Basic. It actually is a programming language released from Microsoft and is used to develop in Windows.
I'm working with Ubuntu 21.10. I'm trying to download it but can't. Can I download it in Ubuntu, and if yes, does anyone know how to download it ?

Comment: Are you wanting to run VB.NET or the *original* Visual Basic 6.0?

Comment: You will want to do this inside a Windows virtual machine. There is no other *reliable* way to do this in a manner that most colleges and universities will accept 

Comment: @David not true, Wine can run *some* applications.  VB.NET and Visual Basic is *not* one of those things though, but it is not true that you can't run windows apps in Ubuntu (you can with Wine)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.  VB.NET and Visual Basic 6.0 **do not** function in Linux, even under Wine.

The only solution is to use a virtual machine running a suitable Windows version.  (VB 6.0 cannot be installed in any Windows later than Windows XP I believe, but VB.NET might be installable in later Windows versions such as Windows 10 though I never tested - I needed Visual Basic for a course assignment too, and discovered the VB6 compatibility limits hence that info here).

Answer (score 0):

Well ... technically ... yes, VB.NET support is supported in .NET Core on Ubuntu.  BUT, as mentioned by @matigo (in the comments) and @ThomasWard's answer, it probably won't meet your needs for coursework.  It doesn't, for example, support WinForms, or (to my knowledge) any windowing libraries (see [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68330044/11810933)).

However VB.NET *does* work under Ubuntu for Console apps (and some other use-cases).

There are [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#ubuntu) specifically for installing on all currently supported Ubuntu releases.  For 21.10, use the 21.04 package:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/21.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Then, to install the SDK:

```
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

To create a new console application:

```
mkdir -p ~/src/vbhello
cd ~/src/vbhello
dotnet new console --language VB
```

To run:

```
dotnet run
# Outputs "Hello World!"
```

Again, the support is almost certain too simplistic for your needs.